# Ember - Rendering issue - Many to Many

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, handlebars.js

HI there and thanks for taking the time to help me out.

I have the following models:

```
App.Project = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    projectTeams: DS.hasMany('projectTeam'),
});

App.ProjectTeam = DS.Model.extend({
    sdeEffort: DS.attr('number'),
    team: DS.belongsTo('team'),
    project: DS.belongsTo('project'),
});

App.Team = DS.Model.extend({
    projectTeams: DS.hasMany('projectTeam'),
    name: DS.attr('string')
});
```

and the following html:

```
<table class="table table-bordered" border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>
        Name
      </th>
      {{#each team in teams}}
        <th>
          team.name
        </th>
      {{/each}}
    </tr>
    {{#each project in model}}
    <tr>
      <td>
        {{project.name}}
      </td>
      <td>
        // WHAT SHOULD COME HERE??
```

Something like foreach team, foreach project.project_teams, if team.id == project_team.team_id print project_team.sdeEffort otherwise..???  If I just create a blank column then I'd have numberOfProjectTeamsForProject-1 columns per team which is not what I want.. I wanted to maybe keep a count of how many

```
      </td>
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
  </table>
```

So basically I have three models as you can see. Project has many ProjectTeams. Team has many ProjectTeams. ProjectTeam belongs to both Project and Team.

What I want to do is the following:

I print out a table with the project name, and as a table header I'm rendering columsn for EVERY POSSIBLE teams there is. Now, for each project, I want to populate the team columns only for those teams that belong to the project I'm iterating over with the value found in ProjectTeam (sdeEffort). If the team in question is not part of the project, I want to render an empty column. I've tried implementing my own handlebars helper methods and all of that, but none of that would work..

Is this even doable in Ember/Handlebars?!

Desired out (table):

```
Project name  T1   T2   T3
__________________________
Project 1 |    | 1  |    |
Project 2 | 2  | 10 |    |
Project 3 |    |    |    |
Project 4 |    |    |  7 |
```

Team 1 is involved in project 1 only, Team 2 is involved in Projects 2 and 3, and Team 3 is involved in Project 4. No team participates in Project 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a `teamsProjectsTable` property on your controller, which is derived from your models, and returns a regular JS object that looks like:

```
{
  teamNames: ["T1", "T2", "T3"],
  projects: [
    {name: "Project 1", cells: [1, null, 1, null] },
    {name: "Project 1", cells: [2, 2, 10, null] },
    {name: "Project 1", cells: [3, null, null, null] },
    {name: "Project 1", cells: [4, null, null, 7] }
  ]
}
```

Constructing this object in Javascript in your property is trivial, and then the view becomes trivial as well.

For example, it could look something like this:

```
App.ProjectsController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  function teamsProjectsTable() {
     var result = {teamNames: [], projects: []};
     var teams = this.get("teams");
     var projects = this.get("projects");

     // do lots of stuff here with teams and projects to make result look like the thing above

     return result;
  }.property(); 
});
```

And in the view:

```
<table class="table table-bordered" border="1">
<tr>
  <th>
    Name
  </th>
  {{#each teamName in teamsProjectsTable.teamNames}}
    <th>
      teamName
    </th>
  {{/each}}
</tr>
{{#each project in teamsProjectsTable.projects}}
<tr>
  <td>
    {{project.name}}
  </td>
  {{#each teamCell in project.cells}}
     <td>{{teamCell}}</td>
  {{/each}}
<tr>
{{/each}}
</table>
```